# Issue in assigning image to UIImageView iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my .h file I have:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
```

and in .m file I am trying to assing image to this image1 like this

```
image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"]];
```

But the UIImageView is not showing anything. Its blank.

What can be the problem.

Comment: Is the file name correct? is it .png?

Comment: Add the image extension and see if that helps.

Comment: yes it is png and file name is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an IBOutlet attached to your property , you do not need to allocate and initialize the imageView again.

Just try :

```
image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue-Jaanamaz-Small"];
```

Also use this if your imageView is not on the top of your view hierachy.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:image1];
```

Make sure that your imageView is not hidden in InterfaceBuilder or somewhere in code.
And make sure your `IBOutlet` is correctly connected to an imageView in the InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: If you add a break to the code where you try and assign the image to the view, I think you may find image1 is nil because it is not properly wired up in IB.  If you have properly assigned image1 to a control in IB, you should never have to alloc, the alloc for controls bound in a XIB is handled by the OS.  Your code would cause a memory leak.

Comment: True. You should remove allocation code as I pointed out. I believe there should be a connection problem between the interfaceBuilder and the header.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connections between Interface builder and UIImageView.